# Проблема с приравниваем булевого значения

Tags: c#, winforms

При попытке приравнять булевому значению булевое значение свойства `IsPhoneValid = phoneMaskedBox.MaskCompleted` `IsPhoneValid` возвращает `false`, в то время как `phoneMaskedBox.MaskCompleted` возвращает `true`. Начальное значение `IsPhoneValid = false`

Полный код данной функции

```
 private void phoneMaskedBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPhoneValid = phoneMaskedBox.MaskCompleted && IsStreetValid && IsNameValid && IsTownValid && IsPasswordValid && IsSurnameValid && IsEmailValid && IsPasswordEqual == true)
        {
            registrationButton.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            registrationButton.Enabled = false;   
        }

        if (IsPhoneValid == true)
        {
            phoneTip.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            phoneTip.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `IsPhoneValid = phoneMaskedBox.MaskCompleted` в скобки

Comment: Спасибо, но такой вопрос, на что влияют эти скобки? Ибо не первый баг ловлю с этим, это приоритезация операций или как выделение метода для If?

Comment: `...такой вопрос, на что влияют эти скобки` - на приоритет операций.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и объяснение) @ヒミコ не могли бы вы написать это в ответ, чтобы я отметил вопрос решённым)

Comment: К сожалению не смогу, у меня клавиатура не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
if((IsPhoneValid = phoneMaskedBox.MaskCompleted))
```

выражение должно быть в скобках